No templates were found in the package [Azure Devops continuous integration]
TLDR
When installing a packaged custom project template I get this output:
No templates were found in the package MyTemplate.Domain::1.0.1.

Background
I have created a sample class library project that is to be used as a template for future implementations and it should provide examples of what type of structure is required for the function it serves.
Project structure
I have created a simple sample project with the following tree:
sln [MyTemplate.Domain]
 |_MyTemplate.Domain (= class lib project)
   |_.template.config
   | |_template.json
   |_interfaces
   | |_IManageBooks
   |_Book.cs
   |_README.md   

IManageBooks
Is to be used by service classes (application layer) that manipulate books. :
public interface IManageBooks
{
    void ReleaseForRent(Book book);
    void Archive(Book book);
}

Books is a DDD entity class:
public class Book
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
    public string Author { get; set; } = default!;
    public int Pages { get; set; } = default!;
    public string Status { get; set; } = default!;

    public void Release()
    {
        this.Status = "ACTIVE";
    }

    public void Archive()
    {
        this.Status = "ARCHIVE";
    }
}

It's not supposed to be very meaningful, just provide a general context.
Template config
I have manually added the folder .template.config with the file template.json to the project structure.
That template.json files contains the following:
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/template",
  "author": "Me",
  "classifications": [ "Template", "C#", "DDD", "Domain" ],
  "identity": "MyTemplate.Domain",
  "name": "MyTemplate Domain Project Template",
  "shortName": "mytemplate-domain",
  "sourceName": "mytemplate-domain",
  "tags": {
    "language": "C#",
    "type": "solution"
  },
  "preferNameDirectory": true
}

My pipeline yaml
I am using the following configuration:
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

name: 1.0.$(Rev:r)

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: './nuget.config'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: dotnet pack
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/MyTemplate.Domain.csproj'
    versioningScheme: 'byBuildNumber'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: dotnet push
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
    publishVstsFeed: 'a28b3df0-f844-48da-b710-8b028b28a868/75bb5107-aab1-43be-aea6-138e7583753d'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: publish artifacts
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    TargetPath: '\\MyTemplate.Domain.Templates\$(Build.DefinitionName)\$(Build.BuildMyTemplateDomainTemplates)'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

To my knowledge this is pretty standard.
If I run the pipeline everything completes correctly. I do not see any warnings or errors in the pack task.
However
If I run the following command:
dotnet new install mytemplate.domain --interactive --nuget-source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/my-company/a28b3df0-f844-48da-b710-8b028b28a868/_packaging/41db8e76-ca11-7368-90bb-3f9dd37c4590/nuget/v3/index.json

I am not sure why I need to provide that --nuget-source, but it seems to find the package at least.
--interactive surpresses a credentials warning.
The output is the following:
The following template packages will be installed:
   mytemplate.domain

No templates were found in the package mytemplate.Domain::1.0.1.

My question

To my knowledge I have done everything I needed to, did I miss
anything or what do I need to do to actually be able to install my
template package?


For  .nupkg NuGet package template, it requires that all templates be stored in the content folder within the package. It's recommended to follow the doc to check the file structure and  .csproj file content.

May i know if you have tried to download the nuget package to local machine, and try dotnet new install <PATH_TO_NUPKG_FILE> to validate if it works? If it's not working, please unzip the nuget pacakge, check the file structure and .csproj file content following the doc mentioned above.
